# EXECUTE in MySQL Stored Procedure gives syntax error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I'm new to MySQL and databases in general. I'm trying to create a MySQL stored procedure but keep getting a vague syntax error: 
"you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sps; EXECUTE stmt USING nn,ee,ll,cc,uu; COMMIT END' at line 11"

If I remove the line "PREPARE stmt ..." then the stored procedure is created. When I put the line back in, I get the error again.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `account_create` (nn VARCHAR(25),
                                   ee BIGINT, 
                                   ll BIGINT, 
                                   cc VARCHAR(100),
                                   uu VARCHAR(25))
   BEGIN
      DECLARE newId BIGINT;
      DECLARE sps VARCHAR(50);
      START TRANSACTION;
      set sps = 'INSERT INTO account SET name=?, entity=?, ledger=?, tblname=tmpXXX,  creation_date=CURDATE(), comment=?, uname=?';
      PREPARE stmt FROM sps;


      COMMIT;
   END//
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a [User Defined Variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html) to execute a prepared statement. Rewrite as:

```
...
BEGIN
  DECLARE newId BIGINT;

  START TRANSACTION;
  set @sps = 'INSERT INTO account SET name=?, entity=?, ledger=?, tblname=tmpXXX,  creation_date=CURDATE(), comment=?, uname=?';
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sps;


  COMMIT;
END//
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it worked. The MySQL docs never clarified the difference between 'varName' and '@varName' and I saw from a previous stackoverflow question that the '@' variables had session scope while the non'@' variables had procedural scope. If my understanding is correct shouldn't the above non'@' version work as well?

Comment: It should not work, simple because you are required to use session variables rather than local variables.